# Equivalent of WCF [DataMember(Name= and [DataContract(Name = in Java

Tags: java, wcf, soap

I have a SOAP web Service between Java and .Net

In .net we can specify the name of an datamember attribut of datacontract
with something like

```
[DataContract(Name = "Class")]
public class ClassWithASoLongNameThatIWantToRenameIt
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Property")]
    public string PropertyWithASoLongNameThatIWantToRenameIt  { get; set;}
```

what would be the equivalent annotation in Java knowing I am using

```
import javax.jws.*;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://MyNameSpace/")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
```

Thank for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the equivalent in Java will be something like

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Class", namespace="http://MyNameSpace/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ClassWithASoLongNameThatIWantToRenameIt {

     @XmlElement(name="Property")
     private String propertyWithASoLongNameThatIWantToRenameIt;

     public String getPropertyWithASoLongNameThatIWantToRenameIt {
           return propertyWithASoLongNameThatIWantToRenameIt;
     }
```